# Compositing Nodes for a simple scene with a lamp?

Tags: compositing-nodes

Here is a simple scene I've created:
www.transfernow.net/1285r198gacg

There are 3 cubes, I've put the white cube on a different Render Layer so that I can apply a particular effect on it (Glare for example, it is supposed to be a lamp). How do I organise my Compositing Nodes? what is the right Node to mix the two Render Layers so that I have the white cube between the two grey cubes? I've tried Color > Mix but it doesn't work properly...

Another question: sometimes when I click on the Render button it gives me the Render image into the Node Editor Window rather than into the 3D View, which is not really convenient as it masks my Nodes, how can I avoid that?

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi. Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for blend file hosting.

Comment: Please do not ask more than one question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one the layers as a mask.

[image]